# addClass to jquery-asProgress.js when value is 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress-bar

I'm using the library "jquery-asProgress.js" to produce 100% complete bar graphs.

Library can be found here: https://github.com/thecreation/jquery-asProgress

I'd like to have the bar change color when 100% is reached.

Current code is as follows:

```
        <div class="progress" role="progressbar" data-goal="15" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
        <div class="progress__bar"><span class="progress__label"></span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="progress" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
        <div class="progress__bar"><span class="progress__label"></span></div>
        </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/jquery-asProgress.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
      $('.progress').asProgress({
            namespace: 'progress',
            bootstrap: false,
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            goal: 100,
            speed: 10, // speed of 1/100
            easing: 'ease',
            labelCallback: function labelCallback(n) {
                var percentage = this.getPercentage(n);
                return percentage + '%';
            }
      });
        
    $('.progress').asProgress('start');

    });

  </script>
```

I tried adding this section to allow a class to be added if the value is 100 but it just breaks the JS

```
    $('.progress').asProgress({
        var percentage ="100";
        $('progress__bar').addClass("wishlist_100");
    });
```

---

#### EDIT:

I've altered using the suggestion by @Roamer-1888, the trouble is that they all get the class applied, not just the Value of 100.

```
    jQuery(function($) {
        
        $('.progress').asProgress({
            namespace: 'progress',
            bootstrap: false,
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            goal: 100,
            speed: 10, // speed of 1/100
            easing: 'ease',
            labelCallback: function labelCallback(n) {
                var percentage = this.getPercentage(n);
                return percentage + '%';
            }
    }).on('asProgress::finish', function(e) {
            $('.progress__bar').addClass('wishlist_100');
    }).asProgress('start');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to establish a handler for the `finish` event;

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.progress').asProgress({
        'namespace': 'progress',
        'bootstrap': false,
        'min': 0,
        'max': 100,
        'goal': 100,
        'speed': 10, // speed of 1/100
        'easing': 'ease',
        'labelCallback': function(n) {
            return `${this.getPercentage(n)}%`;
        }
    }).on('asProgress::finish', function(e) {
        // change colour here.
    }).asProgress('start');
});
```

Comment: Hi @Roamer-1888 I update the code but the trouble is that all of the classes get the class applied, not just the values of 100%. I will post an updated example

Comment: Mmm, not too sure. Try `$(this).addClass('wishlist_100');`

Comment: Documentation is pretty poor. Something else to try is to set each prog bar up with a different namespace - `'namespace': 'progress1',` and `'namespace': 'progress2',`. Then (probably) `.on('asProgress:progress1:finish', function(e) ...` and `.on('asProgress:progress2:finish', function(e) ...`, 
It'll be something like that.

Comment: Thanks @Roamer-1888, doesn't seem to work either. Is there any chance to write a query based on the value [data-goal="100"] that is applied to the parent class "progress" and when that value is 100 the new class 'wishlist_100" is applied to "progress__bar"

Comment: Remember that `$('.progress__bar')` addresses *both* progress bars, not just the one you're interested in. In the event handler, `this` should be the widget whose finish event was triggered. You may need to drill down to find the bar itself, eg `$(this).find('.progress__bar').addClass('wishlist_100');`

Comment: Try `.on('asProgress::finish', function(e) {
       this.$element.find('.progress__bar').addClass('wishlist_100');
    })`

Comment: Or maybe just `.on('asProgress::finish', function(e) { this.$element.addClass('wishlist_100'); })`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this functional using a combination of solutions however it may not be the "right way" to do this.
The limitation present now is that the JS query breaksdown if the value supplied for "data-goal" is over 100, however I will have my backend developer supply a limiter on his end. We're developing using Classic ASP for those curious.

Many thanks to @Roamer-1888 for his help.

```
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('.progress').asProgress({
            namespace: 'progress',
            bootstrap: false,
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            goal: 100,
            speed: 10, // speed of 1/100
            easing: 'ease',
            labelCallback: function labelCallback(n) {
                var percentage = this.getPercentage(n);
                return percentage + '%';
            }
        });

        $('.progress').asProgress('start');

        $(".progress[data-goal='100']").find('.progress__bar').addClass('wishlist_100');

    });
```